# How to use MultiCursor on a Pandas Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm getting an error with this. I suspect I'm not passing the correct arguments to MultiCursor:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import MultiCursor

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"idx": range(0, 10), "colA": range(0, 10), "colB": range(0, 10)})
df = df.set_index("idx")
ax = df.plot(subplots=True)
multi = MultiCursor(plt, ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `plt.gcf().canvas`, get current figure then use attribute canvas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import MultiCursor

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"idx": range(0, 10), "colA": range(0, 10), "colB": range(0, 10)})
df = df.set_index("idx")
ax = df.plot(subplots=True)
multi = MultiCursor(plt.gcf().canvas, ax)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]